# Magento 2.1 - some random error in shopping cart [solved]

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart, requirejs

I am running `Magento 2.1.1` in `apache2.4`.
I always see some random errors in the shopping cart.
The cart cannot calculate the grand total(nothing show) and cannot go to checkout page after clicking the checkout button.
This error happens randomly (around 40%) in responsive mobile version.

[image]
[image: Error 1]

This is another error triggered.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why you run this old version? Update asap to last version.

Comment: Do you mean 2.1.7? I tried before. But no idea why it slowed down my system.

Comment: I updated to 2.1.7. Same errors happen in mobile view. Seems that the JS crashed in mobile view only.

Comment: have you original luma or custom theme?

Comment: I am using custom theme

Comment: if you set default theme luma, is the issue still present?

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason why js crashed in mobile only. Because I added a live chat javascript at the footer and this javascript does not support mobile.

I added a screen width checking to remove the plugin in mobile view and fixed it.

```
<script>
if (screen && screen.width > 480) {
  document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="foo.js"><\/script>');
}
</script>
```